# How to recognize duplicate tweets in twitter?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, spring-social

I am preparing an application to send tweets using Twitter REST API. I want to WARN (duplicate tweet) users if they try to send a tweet already submitted from my application.

Twitter says for a duplicate tweet -

> For each update attempt, the update text is compared with the
>   authenticating user's recent tweets. Any attempt that would result in
>   duplication will be blocked, resulting in a 403 error. Therefore, a
>   user cannot submit the same status twice in a row.

How twitter collects recent tweets?

1. interval of time.
2. no. of latest tweets by user.

No definition available on twitter. Can someone help?

The same thing i am facing with facebook status updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter doesn't publish the exact conditions for duplicate status detection  and they're subject to change over time..

I found a discussion at : https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/800

I assume after 1 month or sending 20 tweets we are allowed to enter a duplicate tweet again. I am going to test with both conditions.

I will try the same 1 month or 20 status updates gap for duplicate insert with facebook.

Comment: out of curiosity, did you manage to find an answer to that question ?

Comment: Not exactly .. twitter sends an error message if we try to send a duplicate message within some minutes.

Comment: I had tried with time interval of 12 hours..and I could post same message again..So i suggest you to try less than 12 hrs instead of going for 1 month